# Adding KOMAscript to LaTeXML

Tags: koma-script, xml, collaboration

Like many people, I prefer KOMA Script classes `scrbook`, `scrreprt` and `scrartcl` over the original `book`, `report` and `article`. Lately I’ve been trying out a web service for collaborative writing, [Authorea](https://www.authorea.com/product), which relies upon either [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/README.html#variables-for-latex) or [LaTeXML](https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML) for its LaTeX processing. The latter doesn’t seem to support `scr*` yet, [blocking its support in Authorea](https://www.authorea.com/issues/438).

What would be the easiest and best course of action to change that if I don’t know much about LaTeXML and KOMA Script internals myself?

PS: Support for [biblatex](https://www.authorea.com/issues/369) (and biber) in Authorea is also not really there yet, for different reasons it seems.

Comment: As I read the linked discussion, Authorea doesn't have much interest in supporting KOMA because it is not required by their target domain. I guess you'd need to look at the extensibility bit of the manual for LaTeXML, but your best bet might be to start an academic journal requiring KOMA.

Comment: The link https://www.authorea.com/issues/438 seem to be dead: *Article with id 121541 does not exist.*